# SQL - Continue running all SQL statements even after error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have some queries like this

```
Alter Table Table1 ALTER COLUMN T1 varchar(MAX);
Alter Table Table1 ALTER COLUMN T2 varchar(MAX);
Alter Table Table1 ALTER COLUMN T3 varchar(MAX);

--Table2 does not have a column "R1" and is likely to give error
Alter Table Table2 ALTER COLUMN R1 varchar(MAX);

Alter Table Table2 ALTER COLUMN T1 varchar(MAX);
Alter Table Table2 ALTER COLUMN T2 varchar(MAX);
Alter Table Table2 ALTER COLUMN T3 varchar(MAX);
```

### Possible Error

Now in the **4th statement** it is likely that a message would pop because there is no field in Table2 named **R1**.

### Need

I need a way so that all the statement gets executed even after receiving the error.

### My Approach

I tried to **execute these statements individually** to receive error message for every line but it takes too much time as it makes 7 times connection to a **server which is connected to the PC by internet** . So, i used all those query together to get records in one connection but it breaks the command on 4th line as the statement is invalid.

Any suggestion or piece of code is appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a try-catch block:

```
Alter Table Table1 ALTER COLUMN T1 varchar(MAX);
Alter Table Table1 ALTER COLUMN T2 varchar(MAX);
Alter Table Table1 ALTER COLUMN T3 varchar(MAX);

BEGIN TRY
     Alter Table Table2 ALTER COLUMN R1 varchar(MAX);
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
     print 'error altering column R1 of Table2';
END CATCH;

Alter Table Table2 ALTER COLUMN T1 varchar(MAX);
Alter Table Table2 ALTER COLUMN T2 varchar(MAX);
Alter Table Table2 ALTER COLUMN T3 varchar(MAX);
```

Comment: tried it but it is not working. the error message remains there without printing the message "error altering column R1 of Table2"

Comment: @FelixPamittan i tried making a new database with no tables in it and used one of your try-catch but it does not print your error message and instead prints system default message

Comment: @DeveloperNation the error is not caught because the severity of the error must be lower than what the catch block should handle. refer to [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) also referred by Sabbegh Houssem in his answer

Answer (score 11):

You should use 'GO' between instructions in order to contine the execution no matter on the errors:

```
Alter Table Table1 ALTER COLUMN T1 varchar(MAX);
GO
Alter Table Table1 ALTER COLUMN T2 varchar(MAX);
GO
Alter Table Table1 ALTER COLUMN T3 varchar(MAX);
GO
Alter Table Table2 ALTER COLUMN R1 varchar(MAX);
GO
Alter Table Table2 ALTER COLUMN T1 varchar(MAX);
GO
Alter Table Table2 ALTER COLUMN T2 varchar(MAX);
GO
Alter Table Table2 ALTER COLUMN T3 varchar(MAX);
GO
```

This will give you all messages and will execute all the sentences one after each other. Those are my logs on a similar situation. As you will see, various errors are notified, and not only one:

[image]

> NOTE: The catch behavior depends on the severity of the error, this
>   link from the MSDOC explains how try_catch works 
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Hope it helps :)

Comment: nice trick. Perfect for my case (lot of table changes. and for me with try catch has no sense. I just need kind of "please continue executing no matter of errors" and this is perfect

Answer (score 0):

If Table2 does not have column R1 then the statement 'Alter Table Table2 ALTER COLUMN R1 varchar(MAX);' will not be a valid sql statement so the statement will not try to run so the catch will not happen.  If instead you execute the statement it will try to run and the catch will work.

```
Alter Table Table1 ALTER COLUMN T1 varchar(MAX);
Alter Table Table1 ALTER COLUMN T2 varchar(MAX);
Alter Table Table1 ALTER COLUMN T3 varchar(MAX);

BEGIN TRY
     execute ('Alter Table Table2 ALTER COLUMN R1 varchar(MAX);')
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
     print 'error altering column R1 of Table2';
END CATCH;

Alter Table Table2 ALTER COLUMN T1 varchar(MAX);
Alter Table Table2 ALTER COLUMN T2 varchar(MAX);
Alter Table Table2 ALTER COLUMN T3 varchar(MAX);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that we get the desired behavior if the commands are run from inside an open session.

`mysql -u root -p myDB < commands.sql` >> stops on the first error

```
mysql -u root -p myDB
(after login)
source commands.sql
```

^^^ continues even after errors occur

Comment: The question is about SQL Server, not MySQL